# Fastest way to open a shaken bottle of soda without spillage

Tags: drinks

We've all been there, we've all done it - Taken out the delicious soda bottle from the fridge, thrown it on the couch, sat next to it only then to realize, that the throw has shaken it and we now have to wait until the pressure has cleared or we are in for an entire afternoon of cleaning.

What is the fastest way to depressurize a shaken bottle that contains carbonated beverage?

Comment: The best I found is simply to 1) wash the bottle 2) open the cap (slightly, to reduce the flow) in a container to collect the foam/liquid.

Answer (score 4):

Swap it for one still in the fridge, and walk away.

There is *no way* to "calm down" a soda quickly after it's been shaken; it'll take a minimum of an hour or so sitting quietly in refrigeration of the carbon dioxide to redissolve and the pressure inside the bottle or can return to its normal value.

The closest I've ever been able to come is to open the bottle very, *very* **VERY** slowly.  And if it's badly shaken, this may only result in getting a soda shower.

Comment: You might want to add a reference about tapping the can not working.  I was going to post an answer, suggesting it but found lots of references that it does not work.  Making your answer the best one I can imagine.

Comment: @JamesJenkins The OP specificallty asked about a bottle, making can references irrelevant.  I never believed tapping, tab-snapping, or other vibrations likely to do anything but make the soda inside the can even angrier -- but that's referential only to cans, not bottles.

Comment: That would be the infamous [John Dorian Three Tap Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ySt9SeZl9s)

Comment: Tapping [can or bottle] frees up any bubbles stuck to the sides, re-gaining a slight air-gap at the top. This will give any new foam more headroom. It's not perfect but it can be very very slightly beneficial. [QI covered it recently, can't find an easy link]

Comment: I came here via a Google search and I've signed up to comment. This is wrong, I violently dropped a plastic bottle of carbonated water on the floor a few minutes ago and after waiting a short while it was fine to open. Too bad that wrong answers get upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't depressurize the can quickly.
**BUT you can make it so that opening the can has less of an effect.**

Bubbles are trapped on sides and bottom of the can. These rapidly expand when open, forcing liquid up.

Just tap along the sides and bottom to knock the bubbles to the top. The gas on top will expand, but no liquid above it to cause a mess.

For reference, watch "Non-Exploding Soda Can" on Youtube.

Comment: In a comment on Zeiss Ikon's answer, James Jenkins "*found lots of references that it does not work*", but unfortunately didn't list any of them.

Comment: The gas on top cannot expand as you suggest.  The can is of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

### Turn it upside down

Turn the bottle upside down, keep it there for maybe 20 seconds, then slowly turn it right side up, and open. This is an old waiter's trick for use with accidentally-shaken champagne bottles... I assume it will work for soda too.

Comment: You might mention why this trick works (assuming it does). In the upright position, the water level is in the neck with only a small area for the air/water interface. When it's upside down this area is many times larger. The CO₂ dissolves back into the water at this interface, so the larger it is, the faster the rate of transfer.

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks for sharing that info. I wonder whether tilting the bottle sideways would be even better since that would maximise the area of the liquid/air interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a nickel and press it against the bottom of the can or bottle. Not sure why this works but you can open it immediately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hack!!..

The reason that the can fizzes when you open it isn't because it now has more pressure. The pressure in the container stays the same no matter what. Shaking it just causes the gasses to bind to the side of the container, on the imperfections in the material. And then when you open it the gas wants to go somewhere and the only way out is.. well through the hole you just made.

Quickest way to stop this from happening... Hold the container as per normal and gently tap the side walls of the can all the way round. Doesn't have to be exact just try to get as much of the surface area as possible...

Open the container.. and say to yourself... why didn't anyone teach me this in school :)

Happy opening.